# Evento Js se ejecuta n veces

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Tengo una pequeña duda en JavaScript

Resulta que estoy realizando un evento con Jquery  sobre los elementos de una clase, pero por alguna razón el evento se ejecuta N veces el numero de elementos de dicha clase ejemplo

```
$(".sltTypeTransaction").change(function (){
   console.log("Hola mundo");
})
```

En mi caso tengo 2 elementos HTML con la clase "sltTypeTransaction" y el evento se ejecuta 2 veces, todo funciona bien pero me pregunto si existe alguna forma de que solo se ejecute 1 vez  ya que en realidad al interactuar con el control no se cambian los 2 elementos al mismo  tiempo si no mas bien cambia un elemento a la vez

De ante mano muchas gracias;

Comment: ¿Y porqué usar clases en ves de id's? O podrías usar el objeto `event`, para que sepas quién está invocando tu función.

Comment: El evento se ejecutara la cantidad de veces que tengas elementos con la clase `sltTypeTransaction`.

Comment: el problema surge al asignar el evento a un elemento por su clase, este se va a ejecutar tantas veces como elementos con esa clase en la vista.
Para solventar este problema debes ser mas específico al asignar el evento, reemplazando la clase por un id, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
> event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
> is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
> but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
> element loses focus.

Un evento `change` solamente se dispara cuando el elemento que lo tiene asignado cambia. Si se te está disparando más veces es porque tienes que tener otro evento asignado a la misma clase (quizá un `click` o un `focusout` o similares).

**Ejemplo de función `change()` aplicada en varios elementos a través de su clase**

```js
$(".sltTypeTransaction").change(function (){
   let id = $(this).attr('id');
   
   console.log("Cambia " + id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="sltTypeTransaction" id="elemento1">
<input type="text" class="sltTypeTransaction" id="elemento2">
<input type="text" class="sltTypeTransaction" id="elemento3">
<input type="text" class="sltTypeTransaction" id="elemento4">
```

**EDIT**

Añadí que lo que se muestre por consola sea el **ID** del elemento que está disparando el evento `change`, a fin de que se vea que el evento solamente está saltando 1 vez y que está afectando solamente al elemento que cambia y no al resto con los que comparte clase.

**Referencia:**  [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)